# How to read object in angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no problems when I read an object in view. For example my code was:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
      var AnswerScheme = $scope.AnswerScheme = tbl_qst_master_answer.getByAnswerId(AnswerIdSelectedByStudent);
});
```

In my view:

```
{{AnswerScheme[0]}} // Then the output will be:  {"myTestData":123}
```

However, I got problems if I want to read in the controller

```
AnswerScheme[0] // Then no results
```

How to read the object in `myCtrl`?

Comment: $scope.AnswerScheme[0]

Comment: What is getByAnswerId method? If It`s a http call you should resolve the promisse before get the value, that`s why you have no results

Comment: So I need to make http calls? I just called the service

Comment: but your service is not injected in your controller?

Comment: Of course I've done that, that was just my sample code only

Comment: I think, `{{AnswerScheme[0]}}` is not coming from the controller, are you assigning rootscope anywhere? `$rootScope.AnswerScheme` ?

Comment: @Fals is it correct my service code?

Comment: @Sravan I called from my service.

Comment: just add `$scope.$watch($scope.AnswerScheme, function (val){
 alert(val)
});` this code one and refresh or call the service again, and check if the alert is coming?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126405/discussion-between-imran-and-sravan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you should use `$scope` to access the scope data,
so, `{{AnswerScheme[0]}}` in view is equal to `$scope.AnswerScheme[0]` n controller

In your service you are returning an object instead of a promise.

`If you return a promise, you can call a callback function.`

**Even though it gets displayed corectly in the view since the scope is always watched in the view.**

As per our discussion if you add `$timeout` in controller you can access that object

The `timeout` loads the scope after sometime, and by that time the scope will get resolved.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
      var AnswerScheme = $scope.AnswerScheme = tbl_qst_master_answer.getByAnswerId(AnswerIdSelectedByStudent);

       $timeout(function () { 
           console.log($scope.AnswerScheme) 
       },900);

});
```

Comment: what is different from the answer i posted?

Comment: Let me try first...I think I've done that before but still does not work

Comment: nothing great, I just explained that what will be in view and what will be in controller and just removed the `console.log`, nothing wrong in your answer.
I just added it in the controller.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)

Comment: the above comment tells that, you have some error in your service

Answer (score 0):

You can read like this, this will contain the object. Also object does not have an index.

you have to just use `$scope.AnswerScheme`

```
 Console.log($scope.AnswerScheme);
```

if its an array you can just use `$scope.AnswerScheme[0]`

```
 Console.log($scope.AnswerScheme[0]);
```

Comment: I knew about console.log..but I got problems with the variable `AnswerScheme` -- it return no value

Comment: you have to use $scope

Comment: I do not know, its not me do that.